# How to recognize tables inside a pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I want to recognize tables inside a pdf files. What SDK is used in C# to recognize tables inside pdfs and some mechanism to read cell by cell, can any one please suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956814/read-tables-from-a-pdf-file-using-c

Comment: Possibile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956078/read-from-a-pdf-file-using-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) is good and its free.  I've never done this in specific but it does correlate to all the major objects in the PDF format.

Answer (score 1):

Tables do not exist inside a PDF as a structure unless it was created as Marked content with additional tagging in it. I wrote a blog post explaining some of the issues with text extraction from PDF files at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/04/pdf-text/